# jPages doesn't recongnise images added dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html, JS script that loads images from PHP/AJAX and put them into a div, a JS will paginate it after that.
when I try manually hardcode my images, all is fine, when I load the images with jquery, the script doesnt paginate them, even when I tried `$(document).ready`

(you can find ipages.js here : http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/js/jPages.js)
HTML:

```
<script src="js/jPages.js"></script>
...
<ul id="itemContainer">
<li><img src="images/test/img (1).jpg" alt="image"></li>
<li><img src="images/test/img (2).jpg" alt="image"></li>
<li><img src="images/test/img (3).jpg" alt="image"></li>
<li><img src="images/test/img (4).jpg" alt="image"></li>
<li><img src="images/test/img (5).jpg" alt="image"></li>
<li><img src="images/test/img (6).jpg" alt="image"></li>
<li><img src="images/test/img (7).jpg" alt="image"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* initiate plugin */
    $("div.holder").jPages({
        containerID: "itemContainer"
    });
});
```

This above works. Now, if I try to append the itemContainer with jQuery, it doesnt work. I see the images but no pagination:
AJAX:

```
 $(function ()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',    //the script to call to get data
            dataType: 'json',                //data format
            success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
            {
                $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                    $('#itemContainer').append('<li><img src="images/profiles/'+value.user_id+'/'+value.profile_pic+'" alt="image"></li>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. You are initiate plugin on document ready. So when dom is ready all current html paginate perfectly. But after doing ajax request you are adding new html element which are dead elements and which are still uninitialized so that html needs to initialized again. So on ajax success request I reinitialized jPages plugin and It works

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',    //the script to call to get data
        dataType: 'json',                //data format
        success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
        {
            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                $('#itemContainer').append('<li><img src="images/profiles/'+value.user_id+'/'+value.profile_pic+'" alt="image"></li>');
            });
            $("div.holder").jPages({
               containerID: "itemContainer"
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are a magician, I hate you :D Thank you dude, it works, but why? could you please explain more why it didnt work after document ready and worked with ajax ???

Comment: yes @Epodax is right, could you please Rakesh explain your code then I can validate and upvote it for the best of the community. Thank you